# Reduce Array to only unique values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array that looks like this:

> ABCZZZZDEFGHGAAA

I want to shrink it down to each letter only once:

> ABCZDEFGH

It doesn't need to be alphabetically sorted.

I want to fill a ListBox so it is important that no empty values are included.

Nothing like:

> ABCZ____DEFGH____

Even Though its a little bit late here a code example I did myself to compenasate for prior mistakes (this could be used as a pretty universal solution for the Problem, hopefully helpfull for somebody in the future)

```
Dim i As integer
For i = LBound(ExampleArray) To UBound(ExampleArray)
    d(ExampleArray(i)) = 1
Next i
```

At least for me this dictionary method did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get a list of unique values with a dictionary

```
Dim Uniques As Object

Set Uniques = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each c In YourArray
    If Not Uniques.exists(c) Then
        Uniques.Add c, c
    End If
Next c

YourListBox.List = Uniques.keys
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Not sure if this is what you are looking for but this delete duplicates in column A
Option Explicit
Sub dupedelete()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dict As Object
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim str As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Do While lastrow > 1
  str = ws.Cells(lastrow, 1).Value

  If dict.exists(str) Then
    ws.Rows(lastrow).EntireRow.Delete
  Else

    dict.Add str, 0
  End If

  lastrow = lastrow - 1
Loop

Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is firstly for a Range not an Array. Secondly, this is a very slow way to do it.